# Are these two for loops the same efficient in python?

Tags: python

```
d = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}

keys = list(d)

for key in keys:
    print(key)

for key in list(d):
    print(key)
```

My question is for the 2nd for loop, is 'list(d)' executed multiple times, or only once? If it is executed only once, it's more compact.

Comment: Sometimes I have to modify the dict in iteration, so I need to get the keys first.

Comment: for, in, calls iterator.__next__() method so creating keys just creates copy of the list of keys in d and yields them up one at a time. If this all gets really big there's a performance hit copying to the list in the first place (memory and CPU) so unless you need to modify the dictionary in loop I'd suggest just using the for key in d approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple test:

```py
d = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}

def _list(*args, **kwargs):
    print("Calling list!")
    return list(*args, **kwargs)

for key in _list(d):
    print(key)
```

And the output is

```
Calling list!
a
b
c
```

It seems that `list(d)` is only called once, so there's no performance difference.

Comment: It's a good experiment, but quoting the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) would be good, too (*"The expression list is evaluated once"*, not sure what marlon found unclear about that).

Answer (score 0):

`list(d)` are an `Iterable`. What you're doing is requesting access directly to that iterator component, and then moving the pointer that it's behind it on every loop run.

Note that the `for loop` is almost a syntactic sugar for `iter.__next__()`, which gives you a mutable shared reference to an item inside the continer on every call.

But when you're assigning it to your `keys` variable, you're copying the whole content on `list(d)` call to some memory location, so yes, assigning it could be more expensive depending on how big is the content to copy.

Comment: So I should avoid use of 'keys = list(d)'.

Comment: It really depends. In complex pieces of code, readability it's more important that efficiency, so you must be aware if it's really making a bottleneck for you, or it's only a little loss. In this case, copying a vector can be really inexpensive (little data, cheap datatypes...) or a huge operation (copy thousand of instances of your own types). The point is that the accepted answer is wrong. There's an impact on the assigment, but may be (or not) expensive depending on the context.

Comment: And how is the accepted answer wrong?

Comment: In particular, `list(d)` does the exact same work (creating a new list, copying the element references, not the elements) whether you do it before the `for` statement or as part of it.  Your answer+comment are rather misleading, I don't think you know Python well. Maybe you're confusing it with C++ (given that you say "vector" and that C++ is your top tag).